# Why is the parameter (t-1) in this example?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

Example 1 on this page: http://mathinsight.org/parametrized_curve_tangent_line_examples

Why do they use $(t-1)$ in the last step ($l(t)=c(1)+(t−1)c′(t_0)$)? Why not just use $t$?

Comment: I guess the author wants $l(1)=c(1)$ and it's why he has to take $t-1$, to cancel out $c'(t_{0})$ when $t=1$.

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer Alright, so I could use just $t$ IF I wanted to?

Comment: I do not know in which particular case you are, but the author seems to say "when $t=1$, the tangent vector must be (...)", so I guess you have to keep the author's parametrization.